# Find the number of products from 2 numbers selected from a set of powers of 2, 3 and 5

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

> Suppose you write all powers of 2, 3 and 5 greater than 1 and lesser than 2017 in one sheet of paper (sheet 1). Then compute all possible products with 2 distinct numbers selected from sheet 1 and write them in sheet 2.
>
> How many integers are there in sheet 2 after you finish all computations?

**Background**: this is question 3 (level 2) from the "Database of questions 2017" for the Brazilian Math Olympics for Public and Private Schools (OBMEP). The answer given there was 155. I'm 9th grader with some math olympics contest experience.

**My attempt**: In sheet 1, the possible powers greater than 1 and lesser than 2017 are

$2^1$ to $2^{10}$ (10 numbers), $3^1$ to $3^6$ (6 numbers), $5^1$ to $5^4$ (4 numbers).

Total is 20 numbers. Then I selected all possible pairs of numbers from sheet 1 to compute the product of them and write on sheet 2. That are

$$\binom{20}{2}=190$$

And that I thought was the answer, but it is not. It is 155. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Be aware, if you pick $2^1$ and $2^5$ that is the same outcome as picking $2^2$ and $2^4$ since they both multiply to be $2^6$, but you counted them differently.  Similarly other issues arise if you pick two of the same base.

Comment: @JMoravitz But the original question didn't specify that the products needed to be distinct.

Comment: @karina.kawa It is implied - would you count $2*6$ and $3*4$ as two different integers just because they are represented in two different ways?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First look at the original numbers.

There are $10$ powers of $2$ as the largest is $2^{10}$

There are $6$ powers of $3$ as the largest is $3^ 6$

There are $4$ powers of $5$ as the largest is $5^ 4$.

---

The powers of $2$ that can be formed are $17$ , the ones between $2^ 3$ and $2^{19}$.

The powers of $3$ that can be formed are $9$ , the ones between $3^ 3$ and $3^{11}$.

The powers of $5$ that can be formed are $5$ , the ones between $5^ 3$ and $5^{7}$.

There are $60$ numbers of the form $2^a3^b$

There are $40$ numbers of the form $2^a5^b$

There are $24$ numbers of the form $3^a5^b$

Adding everything gives $155$

Answer (score 5):

since 2,3,5 are co-prime each $2^j3^k$ will be distinct, as will $2^j5^k$ and $3^j5^k$

$10\cdot 6  + 10\cdot 4 + 6\cdot 4 = 124$

but $2\cdot 2^{10} = 2^2\cdot 2^9$, etc.

The results wiht prime factorization $2^n$ will be $2^3, 2^4\cdots 2^{19}$

or $17$ different numbers.
There are $9$ different numbers that are $3^k$
and $5$ that are $5^k$

$124 + 17+9+5 = 155$